# Как закрасить пространство между виджетами в QLayout?

Tags: qt, pyqt, qwidget

Доброго времени суток! Есть горизонтальный QLayout, в нём несколько виджетов заданного размера. Хочу, чтобы оставшееся пространство между виджетами закрасилось. Подскажите функции или идеи, с помощью которых можно это сделать. Заранее спасибо!

Код главного окна:

```
class GUIManagerWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle(u'Main WIndow')
        self.central_widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.mainlayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.mainlayout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.central_widget.setLayout(self.mainlayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        x = QtGui.QWidget()
        x.setLayout(TopMenuLayout.TopMenuLayout(x))
```

Собственно сам `TopMenuLayout`:

```
class TopMenuLayout(QtGui.QHBoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, parentWidget):
        QtGui.QHBoxLayout.__init__(self)
        self.addWidget(QtGui.QPushButton(u'ololo'),  alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.addWidget(QtGui.QPushButton(u'lolo'),  alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.addWidget(QtGui.QPushButton(u'ololololo'),  alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        for i in  range(self.count()):
            x = self.itemAt(i).widget()
            x.setFixedWidth(50)
            x.setStyleSheet("color:#d0d0d0;"
                            "border:0;background-color:#333333;"
                            "padding:1px;")
            x.pressed.connect(self.button_is_pressed)
            x.clicked.connect(self.button_is_clicked)
            parentWidget.setStyleSheet("background-color:#333333;")
```

Comment: покрасить родительский виджет, не?

Comment: Пытаюсь через setStyleSheet, не красится.

Comment: Приведите код с вашими виджетами.

Comment: Добавил в правке. Ещё, если не трудно, подскажите, как можно задать фиксированное расстояние между виджетами?

Comment: Вопрос, не относящийся к данному, лучше задать отдельно, приложив **полностью рабочий код, который можно было бы запустить**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оставшееся пространство между виджетами - это основной цвет родительского виджета. Его и необходимо установить.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPalette, QColor

class Window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        lay = QVBoxLayout()
        lay.addWidget(QPushButton('Button1'))
        lay.addWidget(QPushButton('Button2'))
        lay.addWidget(QPushButton('Button3'))

        palette = self.palette()
        palette.setColor(QPalette.Window, QColor('green'))
        self.setPalette(palette)

        self.setLayout(lay)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication([])
    w = Window()
    w.resize(150, 300)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

В `QPalette.setColor` первым параметром передается [Color-Role](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpalette.html#ColorRole-enum), вторым - сам цвет.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался и помогло. Плюс к Вашему коду добавил parent_widget.setAutoFillBackground(True) и заработало.